# How can I find number of kinds of data in a row of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, tensor

I have pandas dataframe like this:

```
     id   something  something else 
 1   1    G27        1.45
 2   2    k4         2.52
 3   3    f45        6.45
 4   4    S22        4.23
 5   5    G27        7.55
 6   6    k4         8.54
```

in the row 'something' I want to know how many kind we have(some of them are `G27,k4` and I want number of these labels)
note: I use it for tensorflow(if it has predefined function please say it)

Comment: What do you want to do with the numbers? What is your exact desired output?

Comment: `df["something"].unique()` to get a list of all unique values, `.nunique()` to get the count of unique values.

Comment: I want to use `to-categorical` keras function